# Views do not change according to navbar

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

Hello beautiful people

I'm already some time on this problem and I seem to not figure it out on my own... I hope you can help me. My goal: A working navigation bar which is controlled by php in a project with the pattern mvc.

I want to control the views through a switch in the index file:

```
  <?php 
  // display view according view-parameter
  switch ($view) {
    case 'home':
      include '../view/home.php'; break;
    case 'overview':
      include '../view/overview.php'; break;
    case 'settings':
      include '../view/settings.php'; break;
    default:
      include '../view/home.php'; break;
  }
  ?>
```

The controller changes the views.

```
$view = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : '';
```

I want to include this nav (bootstrap) in my index file above the switch:

```
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php $view = 'home';?>">GG</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="<?php $view = 'home';?>" class="nav-item nav-link <?php if($view == 'home') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Home</a>
        <a href="<?php $view = 'overview';?>" class="nav-item nav-link <?php if($view == 'overview') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Overview</a>
        <a href="<?php $view = 'settings';?>" class="nav-item nav-link <?php if($view == 'settings') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Settings</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Here you can see how I tried to make it all work together with php. Sadly it just stays on the last link  'settings' and all the items are active. This is my current situation.

Comment: You're not setting `$_GET['view']` anywhere in your links. You'd need to `<a href="?view=home"...` etc. somewhere

Comment: `<?php $view = 'home';?>` doesn't output anything. It just sets the contents of the variable `$view` to `home` so your `if($view == 'home')` after will always be true. The same goes for the rest of the links as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here you can see how I tried to make it all work together with php. Sadly it just stays on the last link 'settings' and all the items are active. This is my current situation.

That's because you set value of `$view` variable to given string and check if it is equal to this string's value.

```
$view = 'home';
```

and then

```
$view == 'home'
```

will always be true.

Instead of

```
<a href="<?php $view = 'home';?>" class="nav-item nav-link <?php if($view == 'home') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Home</a>
```

You need

```
<a href="?view=home" class="nav-item nav-link <?php if($view == 'home') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented what you said I should do in all links, it now chooses the home page like it should. Sadly it does not show me other views when I click on a different tab in the Navbar. Do you have any thoughts to that?

Comment: Probably still, because of this line:   <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php $view = 'home';?>">GG</a> you assign value to $view variable here, so that it is always equal to 'home', no matter what you get from GET parameter.